# Kafka Streams application reset tool: Cannot invoke "OffsetAndTimestamp.offset()" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to run the kafka streams application reset tool with these arguments:

```
kafka-streams-application-reset.sh --application-id "my-service" --bootstrap-servers 1.1.1.1:9092 --input-topics "my-topic" --to-datetime '2022-02-12T23:27:00.000' --execute
```

It throws this error

```
Reset-offsets for input topics [my-topic]
Following input topics offsets will be reset to (for consumer group my-service)
ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndTimestamp.offset()" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndTimestamp.offset()" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null
    at kafka.tools.StreamsResetter.resetToDatetime(StreamsResetter.java:506)
    at kafka.tools.StreamsResetter.maybeReset(StreamsResetter.java:448)
    at kafka.tools.StreamsResetter.maybeResetInputAndSeekToEndIntermediateTopicOffsets(StreamsResetter.java:397)
    at kafka.tools.StreamsResetter.run(StreamsResetter.java:167)
    at kafka.tools.StreamsResetter.run(StreamsResetter.java:135)
    at kafka.tools.StreamsResetter.main(StreamsResetter.java:665)
```

Comment: What Kafka version are you using for the script?

Comment: @OneCricketeer 2.8.1

Comment: You may want to try another version of the CLI, at least locally. I recall there was a few bugs in JIRA around that version

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks, I don't get the exception using 3.1.0 CLI.   But when I restart the kafka stream app, I get exceptions saying the task is corrupted.   So it is not safe to use the 3.1.0 CLI against a 2.8.1 streams app & server?

Comment: It is safe. I think the biggest change in 3.0 release was that the `--zookeeper` flag was completely removed from all the tools, but you may want to read the release notes for other things